# c "each" macro doesn't iterate all elements

Tags: c, macros

here is my code, I find "each" macro only iterate first element and output "s1", how to make it iterate all elements?

```
#include "stdio.h"

#define each(item, array) \
    for (int keep = 1, count = 0, size = sizeof(array) / sizeof *(array); keep && count != size; keep = !keep, count++) \
        for (item = array[count]; keep; keep = !keep)

char *join(char const *ss[]) {
    char *r = "";
    each(char *s, ss) {
            puts(s);
        }
    return (r);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char const *ss[] = {"s1", "s2"};
    join(ss);
};
```

Comment: Please don't write macros like these; don't try to change the C language. You can assume that every other C programmer knows C. You can't assume that they know or care to learn about your home-brewed, secret macro language. This is very bad programming practice.

Comment: It doesn't look like a good idea to put a double-nested loop in a macro called `each`.  That logic is more complex than you can consider "boilerplate".  Also, you should user UPPERCASE macro names when you're doing stuff that isn't function-like.  (e.g. a `max` macro might be ok if it uses GNU C features to avoid evaluating its args multiple times.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call `each` from `main`, i.e. place where `ss` is defined, your program works as expected:

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    char const *ss[] = {"s1", "s2"};

    each(char *s, ss) {
        puts(s);
    }
};
```

It works because `each` has access to `ss` declaration, so that `sizeof a / sizeof *a` is equal to number of elements in array.

The problem is that if you pass `ss` array to another function (e.g. `join`), it [decays to pointer](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryptr2.html). As `ss` in `join` is a pointer, `sizeof array` no longer refers to size of array, and expresssion `sizeof a / sizeof *a` yields `sizeof(char**)/sizeof(char*)` which is `1` on your platform.

**See also**

[What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)

Comment: You're right, I use variable parameters to rewrite #join

Answer (score 0):

Considering the below terminology

```
for(initialization statement; condition; update statement) {
       code/s to be executed; 
}
```

Your `condition` has a statement `keep && count != size;` which is checking for the `keep` value to be non-zero.

And in the `update statement` you are doing `keep = !keep` which is making `keep` value to `0`.

Hence your loop is exiting in single iteration. Modify your condition accordingly to loop multiple times.

Comment: It's no reason, I do keep != keep twice

Answer (score 0):

Here macro not creating any problem macro just place code whenever you used,

you need to check your `for` loops ,

```
size = sizeof(array) / sizeof *(array);
```

In above statement `sizeof(array)` and `sizeof *(array)` both are giving `sizeof` pointers. So the `size` is always 1 .

Next is inside or 2nd `for` loop iterate only once because you did `keep = !keep` which change the `keep = 0` ;

So now it's completed first iteration, it going to update `keep = !keep, count++)` , After that it check the condition `keep && count != size` in this

```
keep = 1;
```

`count= 1;` and

```
size = 1;
```

so it is terminating the loop , so check your for loop condition part.

if you have intention to just iterate for all items in char array then there are number of solution do that , I just listing one of them change in your code

In macro

```
for (int keep = 1, count = 0, size = sizeof(ss) / sizeof *(ss); ss[count] != "\0"; keep = !keep, count++) \
```

In main function

```
char const *ss[] = { "s1", "s2","\0" };
```

Now you will get as expected output.